# SSIS project deployment files and updating files

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've recently upgraded several SSIS packages to use the Integration Services Catalogs system.  The packages are generated based on our application's needs (in-house application) and placed into a file folder.

I'm deploying by using the "Import Packages" wizard in SSMS, which works fine if I go through the entire wizard (Select the packages from the file folder, create the .ispac file, and then deploy)

However, I haven't figured out any reliable way to reuse the .ispac file to deploy new packages (from the same file location as the previous files used to make the .ispac file originally)  Many times, I discover that the original files were redeployed and the newer files were ignored.  The .ispac files are way too small to contain the original packages, so I'm confused how the old files get redeployed.

How are the files selected in the Wizard loaded and cached?  Should the .ispac file be reloading packages from their original source, or is that not how it is designed?  Is there a reliable way to replace packages in a Catalog project without having to start from scratch in the wizard?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "reuse the .ispac file to deploy new packages".   Are you trying to create an ispac file, make changes to the packages, and then deploy the new packages using the same old ispac file?   Why would you think that's possible?

Comment: I thought it would be common to want to deploy a certain set of file-based packages to a certain Project in the Catalog, and assumed their would be a way to do it.  (Silly me.)  It gets annoying to fill out the wizard in the same way every time.  Plus, manual steps in deployments are possibilities for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The .ispac files are way too small to contain the original packages

Wrong.   The .ispac file does contain the packages.  It's small because it's a binary file.

If you make changes to some packages in a project.  You need to build the project to create a new version of the .ispac file.   Then you will be able to deploy the new file and it will include your new changes.

Comment: Is there a way to replace a package in a .ispac file without starting from scratch in the wizard?

Comment: @SvdSinner No. You'll have to re-build `ispac` everytime. However, starting from sql 2016, you can incrementally deploy packages. Learn more from here: https://www.sqlshack.com/single-package-deployment-in-sql-server-integration-services-2016/